# XML Data Binding for Common Lisp

Tags: xml, xsd, common-lisp

I'm interested in finding a code generation tool that, given a set of XSD files, will generate a set of CLOS classes from XSD, generate deserialisation routines from XML to CLOS and generate the corresponding serialisation routines. The closest project that I've been able to find is CL-SOAP but it seems to be at an early stage. I need support for XSD elements including xsd:sequence, xsd:choice, preferably xsd:group, and ideally xsd:all. Support for namespaces is essential.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything like that already written, as far as I know. If you find one or write one, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's any open source project which does that, but Franz's SOAP API for Allegro CL can generate CLOS classes from WSDL files.

http://www.franz.com/support/documentation/8.2/doc/soap.htm

There might be a way to generate code from plain XSD files too, but I am not sure. Even if it does work though, it will only work with Allegro CL.